# Installdir on silent installation

Tags: properties, wix, silent

I'm having the next problem, I define a new property:

```
<Property Id="TEMP_DIR" Secure="yes" >
    <RegistrySearch Id="TEMP_DIR" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\$(Company)" Name="InstallDir" Type="directory"></RegistrySearch>
</Property>
```

And then I define a new component:

```
<Component Id="PerformAction" Guid="E2E4E3E5-FBEC-4051-B47B-9347B78105C2">
   <Condition><![CDATA[TEMP_DIR<>INSTALLDIR]]></Condition>
       …
</Component>
```

On regular installation the property is properly assigned and the condition works fine.

But on silent installation, the component is always installed, event if the condition should be false.

On the verbose log it seems like both properties are correct…

**Comment**:

After further investigation, and according to the next link:

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007%28VS.85%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007%28VS.85%29.aspx)

I understood that the INSTALLDIR is being initialize only after CostFinialize action, and the condition fields enable or disable during that action, which mean the property is empty in that stage...

Do you have any ideas on how to initialize the property earlier?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that INSTALLDIR property is set based on user's input somewhere in UI sequence which doesn't run in silent installation. If that's the case, you might want to pass the value for INSTALLDIR as a parameter for msiexec.exe.